# Recursion returning None type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program which finds the super digit of a problem, IE: 9876 = 9+8+7+6 = 30 = 3+0 = super digit = 3 
This works fine whenever the program doesn't call on itself, but in the case above, I will get a final integer value of 3, and it will print as such, but when I go to return it, it returns None. Im wondering why this might be the case?

here is the code:

```
def super_digit(n):
    sup_Digit = 0
    intArray = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
    for i in range(len(intArray)):
        sup_Digit += intArray[i]
    if sup_Digit and sup_Digit < 10:
        return int(sup_Digit)
    else:
        super_digit(sup_Digit)
```

and here is my test case:

```
from unittest import TestCase

tc = TestCase()

tc.assertEqual(super_digit(5), 5)
tc.assertEqual(super_digit(30), 3)
tc.assertEqual(super_digit(9876), 3)
tc.assertEqual(super_digit(11111111111111), 5)
tc.assertEqual(super_digit(12345678901234567890), 9)
```

Comment: It should be `return super_digit(sup_Digit)`

Comment: Ugh, rookie mistakes. That did it, thank you.

Comment: A side comment, line 2-5 can be replaced by `sup_Digit = sum(int(c) for c in str(n))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The return statement causes your function to exit and hand back a
>   value to its caller. The point of functions in general is to take in
>   inputs and return something.

Ok so by default 'return' gives None so in your case you are returning in the 'if' condition's first part when the condition is `True` but where is the return of if the condition goes to 'else' part?

```
def super_digit(n):
        sup_Digit = 0
        intArray = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
        for i in range(len(intArray)):
            sup_Digit += intArray[i]
        if sup_Digit and sup_Digit < 10:
            return int(sup_Digit)
        else:
            return super_digit(sup_Digit)

    print(super_digit(9876))
```

output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return statement:

```
def super_digit(n):
    sup_Digit = 0
    intArray = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
    for i in range(len(intArray)):
        sup_Digit += intArray[i]
    if sup_Digit and sup_Digit < 10:
        return int(sup_Digit)
    else:
        return super_digit(sup_Digit)
```